# is there a dedicated copy application for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Am searching for an app like [teracopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy). Nemo, nautilus, have a pretty simplistic way of showing what is being copied. I don't really like that, as i wanna see what is being copied live.

Answer (score 0):

Try Ultracopier.  Ultracopier is free and open source software licensed under GPL3

> Ultracopier is an advanced and yet easy to use portable application
>   designed to enable users to copy or move files and folders with a few
>   clicks.<sup>[Ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/)</sup>

To download and more info see their [website](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/)